# Embedding Ligature Font in an iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, fonts

I was wondering what happens if I try to use a font with lots of ligatures in my iPhone App? I can't try the font because I need to buy it first, but wouldn't want to waste the money if ligatures were not possible in my iPhone app.

This is the font I'm talking about: [Dear Joe 3](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/joebob/dear-joe-3/)

I tried to use Arabic in my iPhone app and that works perfectly. Arabic is a script full of ligatures, but then again, Apple may be just supporting this particular ligature font for Arabic and no others.

I'd be very grateful if you had any suggestions of how I could test this before I buy an expensive font which won't work...

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is supported for iOS > 3.2 by setting `kCTLigatureAttributeName`

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_StringAttributes_Ref/Reference/reference.html

but why not try other free ligature font first?

Updated again:

---

I've tested on both Simulator and iPhone 4 with a TRUE ligature featured font (yes I was faked by a ligature font without ligature feature before)

here's the result:
Black is UILabel, stroke is CoreText

[image]

And how it should be rendering:
[image]

Take a look on the additional ligature "ll" and the standard ligature "ff"

While setting `kCTLigatureAttributeName` to `0` can remove all ligature
but setting it to `2` cannot support additional ligature like "ll" or "Th" for the font "Bello Pro"
(Default is `1`, that's for ligature like "ff" or "fl")

So I guess there is either a bug in the CoreText engine for iOS or my font is not supported.

Comment: @Edward: Thanks a lot for this. I was looking for ligature fonts online, but it's hard to find them. Do you have any in mind which would be ligature fonts?

Comment: @Edward: This is amazing. Thanks so much for your time. So in other words, if you use a ligature font in UITextView or UILabel, you'll have no ligatures at all (i.e. not the two different ll / ff). If you use CoreText, you have some such as ff, but not other like ll. I don't think the font is not supported, as it is rendered all right in the OS X Text editor. Hmm... all very complicated. I guess its best not to trust ligatures in iOS then. Arabic works perfectly though - even in UITextView - and this is full of ligatures.

Comment: @Edward: By the way, Bello is a pretty nice font - good taste!

Comment: @n.evermind Thanks :-)
If you really want to use ligature in iOS, I think you may need to ask the creator to issue a set of pre-ligatured normal font, but not a true ligature supported font. But setting different font type and detecting ligature for each word is painful.