# Changing value of kCTLigatureAttributeName in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, core-text

I am attempting to use a ligature font in my iOS application, and other answers tell me that in order to do this, I need to set kCTLigatureAttributeName = 2 ([Embedding Ligature Font in an iPhone App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550548/embedding-ligature-font-in-an-iphone-app/5553888)).

However, I am relatively new to iOS and don't really understand how to do this. kCTLigatureAttributeName is declared as a constant - how do I go about changing its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set attributes on an attributed text in the following way:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
    initWithString:@"This is my String"];

[string setAttributes:@{(NSString *)kCTLigatureAttributeName:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]}
    range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

textView.attributedText = string;
```

Don't forget to link the CoreText framework into your project and import the CoreText headers into your code.