# Custom font rendering in iOS versus Mac OS X

Tags: ios, macos, uifont

I'm trying to render a simple UITextView in a custom font in my iOS app. This font is for the Urdu language and I specifically need the stylized look of the characters.

I'm certain that I've followed all requisite steps correctly (the .ttf file's target membership, info.plist entry, finding out and using the right font name etc.), since I confirmed this by logging:

```
NSLog(@"%@", poem.font.fontName);
```

where *poem is my UITextView.

The strange thing is that when I install this font on my Mac and type in the same text in text-edit, the font renders as it should.

Mac OS screenshot:

[image]

Simulator/iOS Device screenshot:

[image]

Any explanation?

Comment: I would guess that this has to do with the lack of ligature support in `UITextView`. Does your text need to be editable? If not, you could try rendering it using Core Text instead (which has better support for advanced typographic features).

Comment: No, the text needn't be editable. Thanks for the pointer, I'll see if I can use Core Text.

Comment: You might also be able to use the ligatures in a `UITextView`, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230399/changing-value-of-kctligatureattributename-in-ios) (haven't tried this).

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: I'm completely new to CoreText, but the font renders perfectly when I did some custom text drawing with it, following some tutorials. 
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I am not familiar with the font rendering system myself. However, I do know that iOS 7 has greatly expanded font rendering capabilities. If you can make your app iOS 7 only, you should really look into this. Unfortunately, the pre-release documentation is currently still down and discussing pre-release features here on Stack Overflow is forbidden as Apple places pre-release software under a non-disclosure agreement.

Comment: @BergQuester, thanks, iOS 7 is interesting! My app is still in its baby phase so I'll see where I can go with it.
I'm quite happy with CoreText custom drawing in UIViews. As long as I can render my custom font in UITableViewCell (by setting its accessory view to my custom drawn UIView), I'll meet all my targets for the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `UITextView`, but instead of using the `text` property, use the `attributedText` property to set the text. That should do the trick, in iOS 7+.

If you want to support iOS 6 or earlier, use `CoreText`.